# Fullfill drf serializer attribute from dict by key name

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Imagine I have a serializer with lower camel-named fields what I have to keep by contract:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    someField = serializers.CharField()
```

And I have following data to serilaize where I want to keep key names in snake case to follow convention:

```
data = {'some_field': 'I love python'}
```

I want serializer to fullfill its someField from dict some_field key's value

```
serialized_data = SomeSerializer(data=data)
serialized_data.is_valid()
serialized_data.data['someField'] == 'I love python'
```

What I tried already:
[DRF serializer source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) - seems to be applicable to model-based serialzers?
[DRF serializer method field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) - seems to be hard to apply when there is few fields of different formats - charfields, datefeilds, intfields and all I need is just to pull values from dict
Custom renderers - but they are applied after serialization and validation will fail and will affect whole view

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried with `someField = serializers.CharField(source='some_field')`?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `serializers.CharField()` you can use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` to get the value from your dictionary.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
someField = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_someFiled(self, obj: Dict):
    return obj.get('some_field', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your client application send data in camelCase but you want to handle to python dialect.

first of all I want you create `camel_case_to_snake_case` function

And then:

leave your serializer like that

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    someField = serializers.CharField()
```

but override `to_internal_value` method in serializer. make it look like that

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
  res = {}
  for k, v in data.items():
    res[camel_case_to_snake_case(k)] = v
  return super().to_internal_value(res)
```